# Is there something similar to JCo.Function.writeXML in the SAP .NET Connector 3.0?

Tags: c#, jco, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm using the SAP .NET Connector 3.0 to interact with SAP RFC's.

What I would like to know is if there is something similar in the .NET Connector to the Java Connector's (JCo) method `JCo.Function.writeXML(someXMLFileName)`?

This method, `JCo.Function.writeXML`, takes the function results and serializes it back into an XML file.

I need something similar in the .NET connector to serialize the output of a function back to string or file, preferably string.

I tried to serialize the results of the function, using .NET Connector methods `.GetAbapObject` and `.GetObject` but serializing both of these blew up errors about the collections not implementing the `.Add()` function.

Thanks.